# Where to write calculation logic in SSAS

Tags: ssas

We are working on a BI stack composed of SSIS,SSAS and SSRS.
Our dataset is a defect database composed of following fields (a subset)

defectid,created date,[last status change date],status

There is only 1 record per defect which is the last status i.e. Open, Fixed etc.

We have a defect fact table and a date dim table which consists of all dates for the reporting period.

We want to compute a month-wise backlog report as follows:

```
Month  NewCount  BacklogCount   ClosedCount
Jan    5         10             6
Feb    4         9              3
Mar    3         10             3
```

Backlog is any defect which is open (but not created) during that particular month
New is a defect which was created in a particular month
Closed is a defect which was fixed in a particular month

Sorry for going to such a detailed explanation of the application. My question is it possible using SSAS to do the above computation. Where will this computation be done? I feel this is difficult using a MDX query.

I am not looking for the exact solution but am looking as where to start?

Thanks for the patience to go through this question.

Vipul